# Split a pandas series into columns and rows using string delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I need to split dataframe column into multiple columns based on string delimiters.

Example:

| AttachedData | Attributes | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| callid='16774327';length='0';vdn='MSIS' | [{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':''},{'id':'1234'}] | 3 |
| callid='18734547';vdn='JGDU';timeout='345' | [{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':'abc'},{'id':'1454'}] | 3 |
| callid='4527181';timeout='356237' | [{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':''},{'id':'4673'}] | 3 |
|  | [{'id':'4365'}] | 2 |

I need to split Attached Data column in below format:

| callid | length | vdn | timeout |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16774327 | 0 | MSIS |  |
| 18734547 |  | JGDU | 345 |
| 4527181 |  |  | 356237 |

And Attributes column in this format:

| Type | UUI | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | 1234 |
| 3 | abc | 1454 |
| 5 |  | 4673 |
|  |  | 4365 |

And final data in a table:

| callid | length | vdn | timeout | Type | UUI | id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16774327 | 0 | MSIS |  | 0 |  | 1234 | 3 |
| 18734547 |  | JGDU | 345 | 3 | abc | 1454 | 3 |
| 4527181 |  |  | 356237 | 5 |  | 4673 | 3 |
|  |  |  | 356237 |  |  | 4365 | 2 |

I have tried to split the data using str.split but it is not giving the desired result

```
s = df['ACDAttachedData'].str.split('|').explode()
print(s)
df = pd.DataFrame(s.str.split('=', expand=True))
print (df)
```

I am getting below output:

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | callid | '16774657' |
| 0 | length | '0' |
| 0 | vdn | 'MSISP' |
| 0 | timeout | '536723' |
| 1 | callid | '18774547' |
| 1 | vdn | 'JGDU' |
| 1 | timeout | '894832' |
| 2 | callid | '4527181' |
| 2 | clientid | '23' |
| 2 | timeout | '567478' |
| 3 |  | None |

How do I convert this to desired format

Answer (score 0):

First off a question: How is this `...split('|')...` related to the input you've provided - I don't see any `|` in it?

Here are some suggestions:

(1) Column `AttachedData`: Make full viable dict-strings, i.e. replace `;` with `,`, wrap the parts left to `=` in string fences, replace `NaN`s with an empty string `""`, and wrap the strings in `"{"` and `"}"`. Then propagate [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#eval) via [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to make actual dictionaries out of the strings, and pull it through [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) afterwards.

```
df1 = pd.json_normalize(
    df.AttachedData
    .str.replace(";", ",").str.replace(r"(\w+)=", r"'\1':", regex=True)
    .fillna("").radd("{").add("}").map(eval)
)
```

(2) Column `Attributes`: Same strategy, i.e. remove the brackets `[`/`]`, replace `},{` with `,`, ...

```
df2 = pd.json_normalize(
    df.Attributes.str[1:-1].str.replace("},{", ",", regex=False).map(eval)
)
```

(3) Connect the pieces via [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df["count"]], axis=1)
```

Result for this input

```
                                 AttachedData  \
0     callid='16774327';length='0';vdn='MSIS'   
1  callid='18734547';vdn='JGDU';timeout='345'   
2           callid='4527181';timeout='356237'   
3                                         NaN   

                                   Attributes  count  
0     [{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':''},{'id':'1234'}]      3  
1  [{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':'abc'},{'id':'1454'}]      3  
2     [{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':''},{'id':'4673'}]      3  
3                             [{'id':'4365'}]      2
```

is

```
     callid length   vdn timeout Type  UUI    id  count
0  16774327      0  MSIS     NaN    0       1234      3
1  18734547    NaN  JGDU     345    0  abc  1454      3
2   4527181    NaN   NaN  356237    0       4673      3
3       NaN    NaN   NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN  4365      2
```

So you might want to replace the empty strings with `NaN`s or vica versa etc.

Anothter point: So far all numbers are actually strings. If you want to change that, then add `.str.replace(r"'(\d+)'", r"\1", regex=True)` to step (1) and (2) somewhere before `.map(eval)` and replace `df["count"]` with `df["count"].astype(int)` in step (3). Or cast the columns afterwards into the required type (with `.astype`).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html?highlight=extract#pandas.Series.str.extract):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AttachedData':[
        "callid='16774327';length='0';vdn='MSIS'",
        "callid='18734547';vdn='JGDU';timeout='345'",
        "callid='4527181';timeout='356237'", 
        ""],
    'Attributes': [
        "[{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':''},{'id':'1234'}]",
        "[{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':'abc'},{'id':'1454'}]",
        "[{'Type':'0'},{'UUI':''},{'id':'4673'}]",
        "[{'id':'4365'}]"
    ],
    'count': [3,3,3,2]
})

df['callid'] = df['AttachedData'].str.extract(r"callid='(?P<callid>\d*)'")
df['length'] = df['AttachedData'].str.extract(r";length='(?P<length>\d*)'")
df['vdn'] = df['AttachedData'].str.extract(r";vdn='(?P<vdn>[A-Z]*)'")
df['timeout'] = df['AttachedData'].str.extract(r";timeout='(?P<timeout>\d*)'")
df['attr_type'] = df['Attributes'].str.extract(r"{'Type':'(?P<timeout>\d*)'")
df['attr_uui'] = df['Attributes'].str.extract(r"{'UUI':'(?P<uui>[a-z]*)'")
df['attr_id'] = df['Attributes'].str.extract(r"{'Type':'(?P<id>\d*)'")
df.drop(columns=['AttachedData', 'Attributes']).reindex(columns=['callid', 'length', 'vdn', 'timeout', 'attr_type', 'attr_uui', 'attr_id', 'count'])

    callid      length  vdn     timeout  attr_type  attr_uui   attr_id  count
0   16774327    0       MSIS    NaN       0                     0       3
1   18734547    NaN     JGDU    345       0          abc        0       3
2   4527181     NaN     NaN     356237    0                     0       3
3   NaN         NaN     NaN     NaN       NaN        NaN        NaN     2
```